# Forms of the verb "to be" followed by "graduated from"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, be

I know the old fashioned way of saying that someone has been graduated from somewhere is to say that "someone was graduated from school". Does this mean that you can say "He is graduated from that university" or "I am graduated from college", or "He will be graduated from school, soon". Are these examples the old fashioned way of using the word graduate and, if so, is it basically structured, as I said, by putting a "to be" verb in front of "graduated from".

Answer (score 1):

["Was graduated from" was indeed correct in the early 1900s because the school was considered to be the one graduating students.](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/is-graduated-college-wrong)

So when the phrase is put into other tenses, they should follow the rules of passive voice.

> Mike was graduated from university. 
>   Mike will be graduated from university. 
>   Mike is being graduated from university.
>   etc.